# Extracting an xml path with rvest

Tags: r, xml-parsing, rvest

Can anyone assist to extract the path from this XML using rvest?  I can revert to character extraction if not, but would prefer rvest.  I'm trying to extract country shapes from an svg file on this page: https://visionscarto.net/base-maps

```
require(rvest)
require(xml2)

doc = read_xml('https://visionscarto.net/public/fonds-de-cartes-en/visionscarto-airocean.svg')

zim = doc %>% xml_node('.ZWE')

str(zim)
#> List of 2
#>  $ node:<externalptr> 
#>  $ doc :<externalptr> 
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "xml_node"

cat(as.character(zim))
#> <g class="country ZWE" id="ZWE Zimbabwe" inkscape:groupmode="layer" inkscape:label="ZWE Zimbabwe">
#>   <path d="M178.84 80.84l.67-.54.16-.54.71-.4.41-.48 1.27-.3.98-.78 1.2.31.5.38.57-.42 1.35-.14 1.34-.14 1.14.2.45-.07 1.53.33-1.28 1.33-.49.3-.3.45.34 1.4.27 1.98-.26.55.36.52-.03 1.17-.58 1.13-.58-.32-.82 1.1-.76.36h-.56l-.58.53-.97.31-1.74-1.41-.75-1.02-1-.9-.56-.13-.71-.8.02-.28-.74-1.14z"/>
#> </g>

zim %>% xml_node('path')
#> {xml_missing}
#> <NA>
zim %>% xml_attr('d')
#> [1] NA
```

Comment: Brucy Bonus for anyone who can decypher `"M178.84 80.84l.67-.54.16-.54.71-.4.41-.48 1.27-.3.98-.78 1.2.31.5.38.57-.42 1.35-.14 1.34-.14 1.14.2.45-.07 1.53.33-1.28 1.33-.49.3-.3.45.34 1.4.27 1.98-.26.55.36.52-.03 1.17-.58 1.13-.58-.32-.82 1.1-.76.36h-.56l-.58.53-.97.31-1.74-1.41-.75-1.02-1-.9-.56-.13-.71-.8.02-.28-.74-1.14z"`

Comment: Namespaces. XML namespaces. Remove the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ` from the SVG and it works (on a tiny test). Not sure how to specify namespaces in `xml_nodes`, which help() says is deprecated anyway....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but as usual with XML namespaces, I never quite understand why:

```
> xml_find_all(doc, "//*[@id='ZWE Zimbabwe']/d1:path") 
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <path d="M178.84 80.84l.67-.54.16-.54.71-.4.41-.48 1.27-.3.98-.78 1.2.31. ...
```

and feeding that into `xml_attr(...,"d") will get the path string.

`d1` is the default namespace, you can see the namespaces in the document with:

```
> xml_ns(doc)
d1       <-> http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
inkscape <-> http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape
xlink    <-> http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
```

The Brucie Bonus question should probably be in another question, and possibly already has an answer - someone must have a way of parsing SVG path string. Didn't I do well?

Comment: Yes a couple of promising node parsers for SVG path parsing - https://github.com/hughsk/svg-path-parser & https://github.com/jkroso/parse-svg-path